# arm-openbmc-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, u-boot, openbmc

I got a BMC project which need to use AST2600. I just start to handle u-boot.
When I enter blow instruction. I got a error when make.

```
export ARCH=arm

export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-openbmc-linux-gnueabi-

make ast2600_openbmc_defconfig

make
```

Result:

```
make: arm-openbmc-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found
/bin/sh: 1: arm-openbmc-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
dirname: missing operand
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
  CHK     include/config.h
  CFG     u-boot.cfg
/bin/sh: 1: arm-openbmc-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.autoconf:77: u-boot.cfg] Error 1
make: *** No rule to make target 'include/config/auto.conf', needed by 'include/config/uboot.release'.  Stop.
```

The project from https://github.com/AspeedTech-BMC/u-boot

It seems like I miss a toolchain for arm-openbmc-linux-gnueabi-gcc. Does anyone have idea?

Comment: That component of the triple is fairly rare. See if just `arm-linux` works; you might have to manually specify certain GCC arguments.

Comment: @o11c what do you mean by "component of the triple".

his code base is getting dozens of times a day in the openbmc project, and that is what I recommend.

Comment: @Johnb Some documentation about "triples": https://wiki.osdev.org/Target_Triplet https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.65/html_node/Specifying-Target-Triplets.html https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/Tuples https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Triple.html https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/config.git/tree/

Comment: @Johnb particularly, the basic triple is "machine-vendor-os", but "vendor" is rarely needed, and often "-environment" is appended. The most common triple today is "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu", which is often simplified to "x86_64-linux-gnu" by omitting the vendor, or misidentified with a vendor of "unknown".

Answer (score 0):

From an openbmc perspectives, I almost never build the uboots independently  of from the bitbake/yocto project, (and when I do, I build projects in x86) Manually building should work, but openbmc (using bitbake/yocto) already has an automated process for building this project with the gcc tool chain that works for the AST2600 [here](https://github.com/openbmc/openbmc/blob/77c0126ab830535b1c8a98521a2eab5f38cb8353/meta-aspeed/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-common-aspeed-sdk_2019.04.inc) and [here](https://github.com/openbmc/openbmc/blob/77c0126ab830535b1c8a98521a2eab5f38cb8353/meta-aspeed/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-aspeed.inc)

If you are planning on using openbmc I would recomened starting with [these instructions](https://github.com/openbmc/openbmc/blob/master/README.md).

- In step 3 make sure to specify an platform with ast2600 (such as the
  evb-ast2600)
- Then in step 4 make you can just built uboot rather then a whole image. Something like `bitbake u-boot-aspeed-sdk_2019.04`, or you can build the whole image, and it take longer but you will have a copy of uboot.

If you have any more question feel free to reach out us in the open bmc email list https://lists.ozlabs.org/listinfo/openbmc, or to our discord https://discord.gg/69Km47zH98.